# Lipschitz Continuity for a function on stable minimal hypersurface immersed in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, minimal-surfaces

I'm going through a proof of Schoen-Simon-Yau's $L^p$ bound on the norm squared of the 2nd f.f., $|A|^2$, for stable (orientable) minimal hypersurfaces in $\Sigma \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, from Minicozzi and Colding's notes (If you have access to their course on minimal surfaces, this is theorem 2.21).  The bulk of the proof is very clear but one 'lemma' is glossed over, and I'm having a hard time justifying it at all.

Namely, **implicit in the proof is the truth of the following statement**: *If $\phi$ is Lipschitz on $\Sigma$ and of compact support, then $\phi(|A|\phi)^{1+q}$, for any $q \in [0, \sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}})$, is also Lipschitz on $\Sigma$ (and obviously of compact support).*

In fact this seems remarkable to me, and not trivial at all, since products do not preserve Lipschitz continuity in general.  I've tried using local bounds on the norm squared  of the 2nd f.f. but I'm just getting nowhere.
As far as I see we either need this function to be Lipschitz so that we can insert it into the stability inequality, or there is some hairier property of this function which is weaker than Lipschitz continuity but still sufficient to invoke the stability inequality.  I'm hoping it's the former...
Thanks for any help!

Comment: What properties of $A$ do we have so far? Does $\phi$ have the same domain as $A$? What variables are relevant here? These may be obvious, but without any context I could provide a counterexample: $|A|$ a characteristic function of some set and $\phi$ constant.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I thought the notation here was pretty universal so I underspecified. Here $A$ is not arbitrary at all (else you are right, counterexamples abound).  $A$ is the second fundamental form on the surface, so $A(x) = (\nabla_x x)^N$.  The properties of $A$ that we have are rather deep, especially for stable minimal hypersurfaces, too much to recount in a comment, especially because I'm not sure which are here relevant.

Comment: Product of bounded Lipschitz functions are still Lipschitz.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see how that helps, because I don't know that $|A|$ or any power of $|A|$ is Lipschitz, and although I know that $\phi$ is Lipschitz and bounded, I don't know that $\phi^{1+q}$ is Lipschitz (unless $q$ is a positive integer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything are restricted to the support of $\phi$. Note that

- $|A|, \phi$ are bounded functions. (as $\Sigma$ is smooth)
- $|A|$ is Lipschitz as [$|\nabla|A||\le |\nabla A|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1516920/show-that-langle-nabla-textrm2-nabla-nabla-textrm2-rangle-le4-te/1517011#1517011) and $|\nabla A|$ is bounded.
- $|A|^{1+q}$ is Lipschitz, as it is a composition of Lipschitz functions ($f(y) = y^{1+q}$ is Lipschitz when $q\ge 0$). So is $\phi^{1+q}$.
- Products of bounded Lipschitz functions are Lipschitz.

So $\phi (|A| \phi)^{1+q}$ is Lipschitz.

Comment: Ah thank you, it seems i overlooked the impact of having compact support on bounding these functions (else $f(\phi) = \phi^{1+q}$ would not be Lipschitz even for positive $\phi$ and $q$.)  

Most of all I did not know about the inequality you used to show $|\nabla |A||$ is bounded, so I missed that $|A|$ is Lipschitz.  Seems like an important and elementary relation, glad to have learned it! Thanks for the great answer.

Comment: If you are reading the proof of SSY, they actually have a stronger inequality when $\Sigma$ is minimal, which is $(1+ \frac{2}{n-1}) |\nabla |A||^2 \le |\nabla A|^2$. (equation (2.22) in the book/note by colding-minicozzi). This extra $\frac{2}{n-1}$ is extremely crucial for SSY to generalize the Bernstein theorem to stable minimal hypersurface in $\mathbb R^n$ for $n\le 6$ . @user3499756